# ssis script task send email to multiple recepients

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ssis

Hello I am using below script to send email from SSIS script task but I can not send email to multiple people. [How Can I Specify Credentials for Simple Authentication in SSIS SMTP Connection Manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43637009/how-can-i-specify-credentials-for-simple-authentication-in-ssis-smtp-connection)
It only works for 1 email address but It throws some kind of exception when I put 2 email addresses in my variable which is of string datatype.

```
EmailRecipient = abc@test.com;abc2@test.com
```

Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Using the logic in the referenced answer, your script would look something like `foreach(string raddress in EmailRecipient.Split(';')) { message.To.Add(raddress); }`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really appreciate your help.